# Interview: In javascript how can we get previous value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently i have attended an interview at honeywell and i was asked a question in javascript  as below:
Suppose i declared a variable a variable x and assigned it to 10.
Than i override it to 9.
now if i print x it will display output as 9 ie current value.

```
 <script>
    var x = 10;
    x= 9;
    document.write(x);
  </script>
```

o/p = 9;

Than how to get previous value of x i.e 10.

Is there any way in JavaScript to get previous value.

Please help !!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

It was a trick question! Once the memory allocation has been assigned a new value, there's no going back.

Answer (score 1):

I assume maybe they were asking how could you save the previous value and get it later on?

In this case, you could simply use a JavaScript array as a stack (push, pop), to save the value as many values as you want, and retrieve them later on in reverse order.

Otherwise, it was just a silly trick question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your later value `x=9` in a closure then it will be available only in that closure and if you write outside the closure then you'll get 10.